# WILL or continuous forms for habits - which is more common?

Tags: difference, modal-verbs, present-continuous, register

Which of the following is more common in everyday speech:

> 1. She is always mumbling to herself when she's reading.
> 2. She WILL always mumble to herself when she reads.

Is that the emphatic WILL (denoting annoyance) or the Present Continuous construction that you are most likely to hear in a day-to-day conversation? Which is more bookish and which is more conversational?

Comment: I would say that the **is** version is more natural sounding. To make it more conversational make it *She's always mumbling to herself when she reads.*

Answer (score 1):

The version with *will* is how a speaker of American English would normally indicate a habit or repeated action.  It sounds like a prediction for the future.  You could use it in a sentence like

> If you're listening at her door, you will know when she has started reading, because she **will always mumble** to herself when she's reading.

but that is more like a prediction for the future than simply a statement of a general truth.

Normally, to indicate a general truth, we just use the simple present:

> She always **mumbles** to herself when she reads.

We do sometimes use the present continuous to emphasize something or to indicate annoyance, like

> She **is always mumbling** to herself when she reads!